# NSString error crashes app

Tags: objective-c

I would like to loop through a string and use each character.

```
int i = 0;
NSString *saveName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"userName"];

for (i; i < [saveName length]; i++) {
 NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[saveName    characterAtIndex:i]];
 [self setUserName:temp];
}
```

I get an

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'stringWithString:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

which crashes the app.

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `-stringWithString:`, which expects an NSString* argument. But this call:

```
[saveName characterAtIndex:i]
```

doesn't return an NSString, it returns a `unichar`. Try:

```
[saveName substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]
```

there instead to get the character "as a string".